# How to add integration test to gradle kotlin dsl?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following project structure as below:

```
foo/src/main/
        kotlin/
        resources

foo/src/test/
        kotlin/
        resources

foo/src/integration-test/
        kotlin/
        resources
```

I have the following gradle file:

```
dependencies {

    implementation(project(":common"))
    implementation(rootProject.libs.awssdk.lambda)
    implementation(rootProject.libs.awssdk.kinesis)
    implementation(rootProject.libs.awssdk.dynamodb)
    implementation(rootProject.libs.lambda.events)
    implementation(libs.awssdk.client)
    testImplementation(libs.junit.pioneer)
}

sourceSets {
    create("integrationTest") {
        java.srcDir("src/integration-test/kotlin")
        resources.srcDir("src/integration-test/resources")
    }
}

tasks {
    named<Test>("integrationTest") {
        description = "Runs Integration Tests"
        testClassesDirs = sourceSets["integrationTest"].output.classesDirs
        classpath += sourceSets["integrationTest"].runtimeClasspath
    }
}

tasks.withType<Jar>() {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
    configurations["compileClasspath"].forEach { file: File ->
        from(zipTree(file.absoluteFile))
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to create a source set called `integrationTest` which I can use to run my integration tests. When I try to build the project I get the following error:

Task with name 'integrationTest' not found in project `':foo'`.

Comment: The documentation seems to cover this, no? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#ex-setting-up-working-integration-tests